# Woocommerce: Hide Other Shipping Rate When COD Payment Gateway Selected

Tags: javascript, php

i found this code, you can use, but it's not working if you use thirdparty plugin like table rate..please use snippet plugin if you don't know how to install..

PHP CODE:

```
// Assuming you're working in WordPress or some other PHP-based system with WooCommerce

// Enqueue the script in your theme's functions.php or a custom plugin file
function enqueue_custom_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-script.js', array('jquery'), null, true);

    // Pass the URL to admin-ajax.php to your script
    wp_localize_script('custom-script', 'ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_script');

// Add an action to handle the AJAX request
function handle_cod_selection() {
    // Check if the COD payment method is selected
    if ($_POST['payment_method'] == 'cod') {
        // If COD is selected, hide the shipping options
        update_option('woocommerce_ship_to_countries', 'disabled');
    } else {
        // If another payment method is selected, show the shipping options
        update_option('woocommerce_ship_to_countries', 'all');
    }
    
    die(); // This is required to return a proper result
}
add_action('wp_ajax_handle_cod_selection', 'handle_cod_selection');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_handle_cod_selection', 'handle_cod_selection');
```

JS CODE:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // Listen for changes in the payment method
    $('form.checkout').on('change', 'input[name="payment_method"]', function () {
        var paymentMethod = $(this).val();

        // Perform an AJAX request to handle the payment method selection
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
            data: {
                action: 'handle_cod_selection',
                payment_method: paymentMethod
            },
            success: function (response) {
                // Handle the success response if needed
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Hide all shipping rate when choose cod payment

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not clear what your actual question is. In what way is it not working? It looks like you're trying to hide some UI elements in response to a particular user action, but what actually happens? Any errors or messages in the browser's console? Please edit your question and add the code of the `update-option` function and the HTML markup that you're trying to show / hide. See also [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)